# Intending to select user role while creating the node to control the node visibility

Tags: users

I have simple requirement.

I have multiple user roles. What I want is that when I create a node, I could select a role of the user which is able to see this node.

Or may be by default all roles are selected and I could deselect them to modify the visibility.

Any module or help?

Best.

Answer (score 0):

try one of the following:

[Node Access:](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_access)

> The modules provide roles and user specific security permissions for
>   menus, menu items, nodes, and security integration into the
>   administration and help systems.

[nodeaccess:](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess)

> Nodeaccess is a Drupal access control module which provides view, edit
>   and delete access to nodes. Users with the 'grant node permissions'
>   permission will have a grant tab on node pages which allows them to
>   grant access to that node by user or role.

[Content Access:](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.